# Using Image component without it blocking touch

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use an Image component to display an overlay in my app but without it blocking the touchable elements underneath. Is there anything I'm missing or is this just not possible? I've looked through the docs, but I'm not seeing anything. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pointerEvents="none" and the touch events will be ignore by the component that it is applied and it's children, or also pointerEvents="box-none" it will only ignore that element. Ex:

```
<View>
<ImageView pointerEvents="box-none" src=... />
<SomeComponent ... />
</VieW>
```